# How to upload arules package in R

Tags: r, arules

I am not able to upload arules package
Below is the following command I am using

```
library(arules)
```

I have downloaded the file from http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arules/index.html still it is not able to upload it.
Can anyone help me out

Comment: Have you installed it? `install.packages("arules")`

Answer (score 5):

```
install.packages("arules")
```

pls. find below GUI - Screen for `Rcmdr` Package
Open `RStudio`.
Go to the `“Packages”` tab and click on `“Install Packages”`. The first time you’ll do this you’ll be prompted to choose a `CRAN mirror`. R will download all necessary files from the server you select here. Choose the location closest to you (probably “USA CA 1” or “USA CA 2”, which are housed at UC Berkeley and UCLA, respectively).

[image]

Install packages in Windows
Start typing `“Rcmdr”` until you see it appear in a list. Select the first option (or finish typing `Rcmdr`), ensure that “Install dependencies” is checked, and click “Install”.
Install Rcmdr in Windows
Wait while all the parts of the R Commander package are installed.

Comment: Select the Tic mark over the solution - to make this answer , if you find it helpful !!

Comment: Additiona Note: in widows i.e. open 
C:\Program Files\Microsoft\R Open\R-4.0.2\bin 
And then run this command install.packages("arules")
as this post said.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. I solve it using

```
#install and load devtools to install directly from github
install("devtools")    
library("devtools")
install_github("mhahsler/arules")
```

Comment: Missing bracket on `install("devtools"`

Comment: I fixed the missing parenthesis and this works. HOWEVER, if you follow this solution, RStudio will also ask you to install RTools. You'll then need to restart RStudio. This will work so long as arules is still hosted at this git page, and is compatible with the latest version of R/RStudio.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install "arules" package, you may not be able to install it just using the code below.
<<  install.packages("arules")  >>

follow the steps in order to solve problem:

1. go to the package's address and download it manually.you will find it in the link below:
   https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arules/index.html
2. If you are using R-Studio just install that package you have got, by "tools" menu in your IDE (R-studio)
   Tools->Install packages->...

brows the file in your computer and install it.

3. go to the command line and using library(arules) function test the package. If there is still an error it could belong to incompatibility of the package with the version of R (Not R-Studio or any other IDE that you are using), just upgrade R and try installation period again.

Answer (score 0):

I had a related problem where I could not install arules after being able to successfully install many libraries. I finally learned that I needed to update to 3.4 for arules. In order to do that, I followed duckmayr's answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46214061/how-to-upgrade-r-in-linux).  Then, I was able to install arules with no issues, and it worked.