# packages installation for arules in R

Tags: r, arules, market-basket-analysis

I have the same problem with previous post by another user [How to upload arules package in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21453732/how-to-upload-arules-package-in-r)

i am using R version 3.0.2 (32-bit)

The error message is like this:

```
> install.packages("arules")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/HKGGAIT001/Documents/R/win-library/3.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.ms.unimelb.edu.au/bin/windows/contrib/3.0/arules_1.1-1.zip'
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  cannot open URL 'http://cran.ms.unimelb.edu.au/bin/windows/contrib/3.0/arules_1.1-1.zip'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) :
  cannot open: HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Warning in download.packages(pkgs, destdir = tmpd, available = available,  :
  download of package ‘arules’ failed
```

Is that means the packages no longer available? Plus, is there any other packages for market basket analysis?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 7):

If you want to install "arules" package, you may not be able to install it just using the code below.

```
<<  install.packages("arules")  >>
```

Follow the steps:

1. Go to the package's address and download it manually. You will find it in the link below:

   https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arules/index.html
2. If you are using R-Studio just install that package you have got, by "tools" menu in your IDE (R-studio)

   Tools->Install packages->...

   Browse the file in your computer and install it.
3. Go to the command line and using library(arules) function test the package. If there is still an error it could belong to incompatibility of the package with the version of R (Not R-Studio or any other IDE that you are using), just upgrade R and try installation period again.

Answer (score 0):

That repository doesn't have it. You should use a more complete repository.

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/

Comment: Hi. Then what i should do for a more complete repository?

Comment: Well I generally use the Berkeley repo but the main CRAN repo is also available.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by updating R itself.I was running version 3.2 and upgraded it to 3.4 by using the following commands form https://www.biostars.org/p/88651/

```
sudo su

echo "deb http://www.stats.bris.ac.uk/R/bin/linux/ubuntu precise/" >> /etc/apt/sources.list

apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9

apt-get update

apt-get upgrade
```

Afterwards i could install arules package manually, by first downloading arules from

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arules/index.html .

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to install the package "arules"
And I got generating an error. It asked me to install R-Console version 4.0.0 on my computer.

https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2020-06-03/bin/windows/base/

With that, I was able to install the package.