# How to upgrade R in linux?

Tags: r, linux, upgrade, linux-mint

I am new to Linux. I am using Linux mint 18.1. I have installed R using system software manager. My current R version is 3.2. But I want to upgrade it to version 3.4.

How can I do it?

Comment: https://github.com/lmmx/devnotes/wiki/Updating-R-on-Linux

Comment: See also here for an answer using bash and Debian; should be simple enough to adapt to mint. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56017309/939418

Answer (score 48, accepted):

---

**Note**: I now keep on GitHub ([here](https://github.com/duckmayr/install-update-r-on-linux)) an up-to-date guide to upgrading R on Linux Mint or Ubuntu Linux, which also includes a bit of extra information about system dependencies for `tidyverse`, the popular set of data-wrangling packages, as well as `devtools`, the popular R package development... package.

---

The link provided by [FedRo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8369374/fedro) is a good resource, however a slight change would need to be made since you're using Linux Mint 18.1 which uses Xenial repositories rather than Trusty repositories (see [here](https://www.linuxmint.com/download_all.php)). I also typically use the approach [here](https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/debian/) to deal with packages I've already installed when I upgrade R rather than the approach offered by FedRo. So, for completeness, these are all the steps you'd need to take:

#### Step 1

Go to [CRAN's list of mirrors](https://cran.r-project.org/mirrors.html) and find the URL of the mirror that is closest to you. The terminal commands below assume you choose http://cran.wustl.edu/

#### Step 2

Open a terminal and enter the following commands<sup>1</sup> (replacing http://cran.wustl.edu/ with whichever CRAN mirror URL you chose in step 1):

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
sudo echo "deb http://cran.wustl.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade r-base r-base-dev
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Note also that I have put to upgrade `r-base` and `r-base-dev`, but I don't know if you have `r-base-dev` installed. If not, I highly recommend you install it via `sudo apt install r-base-dev`.

#### Step 3

Start a new R session and run the following:

```
update.packages(checkBuilt=TRUE, ask=FALSE)
```

Then you should be good to go.

### Update: Linux Mint 19 and R 3.6.x

Since both Linux Mint and R have seen upgrades since I answered this question, I'm updating for those who come to this answer needing the info for Linux Mint 19 and R 3.6.x.

The only difference is that instead of the command

```
sudo echo "deb http://cran.wustl.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
```

you need to use

```
sudo echo "deb http://cran.wustl.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
```

(replacing http://cran.wustl.edu/ with whichever CRAN mirror URL you chose in step 1)

---

<sup>1</sup> I put here the full key, though many other guides you may see will use only the "short key."
I have updated this guide to use the full key out of security concerns (see [here](https://forums.sonarr.tv/t/ubuntu-apt-repo-key-collision-security-concern/20285), for example).

Answer (score 7):

Now it is very simple. Just make:

```
install.packages("ropenblas")
ropenblas::rcompiler()
```

Comment: Hi, it appears to not be working on R 4.3.3. due to incorrect download url

Comment: Try `ropenblas::rcompiler("4.3.3")`.