# Upgrading R on linux mint

Tags: r

I am trying to upgrade R 3.2.3-4 on Linux mint to at least version 3.4.4 (or any available there after).

Sadly, I'm struggling, and all Google efforts have failed.

I have repeated the same process several times using different locations, all have failed. My latest in /etc/apt/sources.list for R is:

```
deb https://www.stats.bris.ac.uk/R/ precise/
```

executing sudo apt-get update yields the error:

```
Err:13 https://www.stats.bris.ac.uk/R precise/ Packages
  404  Not Found
```

A `sudo-apt get install r-base` failed to update the current version.

I've tried several mirrored sites and they all return a 404.

Any ideas?

Comment: 404 error normally tells us you the website is not available, maybe try it again after a while again. Also did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46214061/how-to-upgrade-r-in-linux)?

Comment: [Visit this URL](https://www.stats.bris.ac.uk/R/bin/linux/ubuntu/), you'll see the `precise` repository does not exist at that location. Try using one of the repositories that does exist.

Comment: Precise had it's end of life in 2017. What version of mint are you using?

Comment: I did this for my linux mint and it worked https://stackoverflow.com/a/50634298/786542

Answer (score -1):

https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/

`deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu artful/
  or
deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/
  or
deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/
  or
deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian jessie-cran34/
  or
deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian stretch-cran34/`